# How do I match something only if a character doesn't follow a pattern?

Tags: ruby, regex, numbers

I"m using Ruby 2.4  How do I write a regular expression that matches a series of numbers, the plus sign and then any sequence that follows provided that sequence doesn't contain another number?  For example, this would match per my rules

```
23+abcdef
```

as would this

```
1111111+  __++
```

But this would not

```
2+3
```

Neither would this

```
2+ L43
```

I tried this but was unsuccessful ...

```
/\d+[[:space:]]*(\+|plus).*([^\d]|$)/i.match(mystr)
```

Comment: `(\+|plus)` – do you also want to match the word `plus` in addition to `+`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
r = /\A   # match beginning of string
     \d+  # match one or more digits
     \+   # match plus sign
     \D*  # match zero or more characters other than a digit
     \z   # match end of string
    /x    # free-spacing regex definition mode

"23+abcdef".match?(r)
  #=> true
"1111111+  __++".match?(r)
  #=> true
"23 abcdef".match?(r)
  #=> false
"2+3".match?(r)
  #=> false
"2+ L43".match?(r)
  #=> false
```

If at least one character that is not a digit is to follow `'+'`, change  `\D*` in the regex to `\D+`.

Comment: you can also use `\D` instead of `[^\d]`